# MySQL syntax Error; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 4

Tags: mysql

I get the following mySQL error listed below and was wondering how can I fix it.

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 4
```

Here is my MySQL code below.

```
$q = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT tags.tag) FROM tags INNER JOIN articles_tags ON articles_tags.tag_id = tags.id INNER JOIN users ON articles_tags.user_id = users.user_id WHERE users.active IS NULL AND users.deletion = 0";
$r = mysqli_query ($mysqli, $q) or trigger_error("Query: $q\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($mysqli));
$row = mysqli_fetch_array ($r);
$records = $row[0];
```

Here is my tables.

```
CREATE TABLE tags (
id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
tag VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);


CREATE TABLE articles_tags (
id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
tag_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
article_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
date_created DATETIME NOT NULL,
unique_id CHAR(32) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
UNIQUE KEY (tag_id, unique_id)
);
```

Comment: the query seems ok , you sure this is the query ?

Comment: yes its the only query I have in the page?

Comment: any suggestions on what it might be, so I can look for it?

Comment: I'd verify it really was this query by putting some unique text in the trigger_error message...

Comment: hey, show the structure of users table too :]

Answer (score 0):

The query seems to be ok... i supose this can be an issue because of `DISTINCT` function...
Try this:

```
$q = "SELECT COUNT(tags.tag) FROM tags INNER JOIN articles_tags ON articles_tags.tag_id = tags.id INNER JOIN users ON articles_tags.user_id = users.user_id WHERE users.active IS NULL AND users.deletion = 0 GROUP BY tags.tag";
```

Comment: then show us the columns from table... simple run SHOW COLUMNS FROM tablename %)

Answer (score 0):

The mysql_fetch_array needs 2 arguments. It is

```
mysql_fetch_array(result, result_type)
```

Possible result types are MYSQL_ASSOC, MYSQL_NUM, and MYSQL_BOTH.

You might want to also see the mysql_fetch_assoc function which could be of help.

Comment: The line $r = mysqli_query ($mysqli, $q) or trigger_error("Query: $q\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($mysqli)); is choosing trigger_error then. In result, this means that mysqli_query ($mysqli, $q) is not resolving. This could be due to an error in your  select statement. Therefore what gets stored in $r is not an array, thus the error. Try fixing your select statement (check if it corresponds correctly to your tables etc.)